# use CASE with SQLITE for matching fields

Tags: view, sqlite, case

I have an SQLite database with student names. Each student has different classes. I have a table with student grades and classes and another table that defines class by type. I'd like to run a query (that I'll be saving as a CSV to use in OpenOffice as an Excel document for a mail merge). I need to list the student's Math grade, History grade, Science grade, and English grade. However, some students have more than 1 math, science, English, or history class.
(How) could I create a CASE statement (and possibly a view) that if indeed there is more than one Math class that it can be listed in a view as Math_Class_2 for Example?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean there. Can we have some basic table definitions and example of desired output, please?

Comment: I made a Python workaround... Not quite I wanted, but close enough. Would it be possible to replicate the following code as views created with case statements:
`cursor.execute('SELECT DISTINCT student_id, course_title, final_grade FROM math_class')
    for row in cursor:
        student_id = row[0]
        course_title = row[1]
        final_grade = row[2]
        if student_id == old_student_id:
                  if student_id != second_round_id: 
                                 ...                                write_string = "INSERT INTO math_class_2_2010 ...`

Comment: There's a table:
TABLE eoygrades_2010 (student_id INTEGER CHAR(6) NOT NULL, course_title VARCHAR(16), grade INTEGER CHAR(3));

and I wanted to create a case statement to display a math class if it hadn't been displayed.
Instead of:
Eddie, Algebra, 90
Eddie, Geometry, 80
I might be able to print a single line
Eddie, Algebra, 90, Geometry, 80
and for those with only one math class:
Suzy, Pre-Cal, 85,,

Comment: Basically, the Python workaround creates an extra table for each additional class. Could similar output (not new tables) have been created with only SQL statements?

Comment: Ah! I see. Well, unfortunately for you, I don't believe SQLite has a `CASE` statement. Building several queries might not be such a bad idea...

Comment: SQLite does have a case statement (now). I had remembered it not having a CASE statement (or at least not near the level of MySQL), but there seems to be at least some basic CASE functionality now. Who knows, maybe the rest of the JOIN statements will show up when no one is looking...

Comment: Oh my, yes! http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to make SQL do the work, and not do it for it.

Assuming three tables:

Student (StudentNo, StudentName)

Class (ClassNo, ClassName)

Result (ClassNo, StudentNo, Grade)

The query will be:

```
SELECT StudentName, group_concat(ClassName || "," || Grade)
FROM Student
INNER JOIN Result ON Result.StudentNo=Student.StudentNo
INNER JOIN Class ON Result.ClassNo=Class.ClassNo
GROUP BY Student.Studentno;
```

(group_concat is another late addition to SQlite. Present in 3.7).

Here's a dump of all the commands I used:

```
CREATE TABLE [Student] (
[StudentNo] INTEGER  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
[StudentName] TEXT  NULL
);
INSERT INTO "Student" VALUES(1,'Jimmy');
INSERT INTO "Student" VALUES(2,'Bob');
INSERT INTO "Student" VALUES(3,'Anna');
CREATE TABLE [Class] (
[ClassNo] INTEGER  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
[ClassName] TEXT  NULL
);
INSERT INTO "Class" VALUES(1,'English');
INSERT INTO "Class" VALUES(2,'Algebra');
INSERT INTO "Class" VALUES(3,'Geometry');
INSERT INTO "Class" VALUES(4,'Pre-Cal');
CREATE TABLE [Result] (
[StudentNo] INTEGER  NOT NULL,
[ClassNo] INTEGER  NOT NULL,
[Grade] INTEGER  NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY ([StudentNo],[ClassNo])
);
INSERT INTO "Result" VALUES(1,1,70);
INSERT INTO "Result" VALUES(1,2,75);
INSERT INTO "Result" VALUES(1,3,80);
INSERT INTO "Result" VALUES(2,1,85);
INSERT INTO "Result" VALUES(2,2,90);
INSERT INTO "Result" VALUES(3,4,95);
```

Running the query returns this (you might want to adjust your separating character):

`Jimmy,English,70,Algebra,75,Geometry,80`

`Bob,English,85,Algebra,90`

`Anna,Pre-Cal,95`

Answer (score 0):

My two cents...

I am currently working on an android app that uses a sqlite database.
I needed to use a CASE statement and it ***worked!!!***.

The table has a column with a time frequency value in milliseconds, but for the end user I needed to show the information in a easier way to understand, so this is the sql statement that I used (by the way, this statement is put together programatically... it is not hardcoded) :-p

```
SELECT 
case when alarm_time_frequency='0' then 'Not Used' 
when alarm_time_frequency='300000' then '5 min' 
when alarm_time_frequency='600000' then '10 min' 
when alarm_time_frequency='900000' then '15 min' 
when alarm_time_frequency='1800000' then '30 min' 
when alarm_time_frequency='3600000' then '1 hour' 
when alarm_time_frequency='7200000' then '2 hours' 
when alarm_time_frequency='10800000' then '3 hours' 
when alarm_time_frequency='14400000' then '4 hours' 
when alarm_time_frequency='21600000' then '6 hours' 
when alarm_time_frequency='28800000' then '8 hours' 
when alarm_time_frequency='43200000' then '12 hours' 
when alarm_time_frequency='86400000' then '24 hours' 
end 
as alarm_time_frequency FROM ALARMS 

I hope this helps...
```